# loose xsd validation

Tags: soap, xsd, xsd-validation

I'm calling a webservice and I would like to validate the soap response with a xsd validation.I really don't want to do a strict xsd validation, I just want to know if some element "History" is present in the response.

So the xsd validation should be succesful when there is a "History element" and fail when this element is not present. I've been starting with the xsd below. I just want to expand it with my mandatory "History" element. How can I achieve this?

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:ns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        targetNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xsd:element name="Envelope">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:any namespace="##any" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="skip"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

**Soap Response**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <p793:TuDetailsResponse xmlns:p793="http://gls-group.eu/Tracking/">
         <p793:History>
            <p793:Date>
               <p793:Year>2012</p793:Year>
               <p793:Month>10</p793:Month>
               <p793:Day>12</p793:Day>
               <p793:Hour>9</p793:Hour>
               <p793:Minut>52</p793:Minut>
            <p793:ReasonName/>
         </p793:History>
         <p793:History>
            <p793:Date>
               <p793:Year>2012</p793:Year>
               <p793:Month>10</p793:Month>
               <p793:Day>12</p793:Day>
               <p793:Hour>5</p793:Hour>
               <p793:Minut>45</p793:Minut>
            </p793:Date>
            <p793:ReasonName/>
         </p793:History>
      </p793:TuDetailsResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you let the XSD validator know about the *TuDetailsResponse* and *History* elements then when it sees them in an *any*, it should use the rules defined for them.

**Main.xsd**

[image: Main.xsd]

**TuDetailsResponse.xsd**

[image: TuDetailsResponse.xsd]

**Main.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML Studio 2013 Designer Edition (Trial) 11.0.0.0 (http://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema xmlns:ns0="http://gls-group.eu/Tracking/"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           targetNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:import schemaLocation="C:\Temp\TuDetailsResponse.xsd"
               namespace="http://gls-group.eu/Tracking/" />
    <xs:element name="Envelope">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:any minOccurs="0"
                        maxOccurs="unbounded"
                        namespace="##any"
                        processContents="lax" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**TuDetailsResponse.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML Studio 2013 Designer Edition (Trial) 11.0.0.0 (http://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://gls-group.eu/Tracking/"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           targetNamespace="http://gls-group.eu/Tracking/"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="TuDetailsResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="History"
                            maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:any minOccurs="0"
                                    maxOccurs="unbounded"
                                    namespace="##any" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**Sample Valid XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid XML Studio 2013 Designer Edition (Trial) 11.0.0.0 (http://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<Envelope xmlns:tns="http://gls-group.eu/Tracking/"
          xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ Main.xsd">
    <Body>
        <tns:TuDetailsResponse>
            <tns:History></tns:History>
        </tns:TuDetailsResponse>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Note The Body element may cause a warning to be generated.

**Invalid XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid XML Studio 2013 Designer Edition (Trial) 11.0.0.0 (http://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<Envelope xmlns:tns="http://gls-group.eu/Tracking/"
          xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ file:///C:/Temp/WSDL%20Sample.xsd">
    <Body>
        <tns:TuDetailsResponse>
        </tns:TuDetailsResponse>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Generates the error

*(9:11) Error The element 'TuDetailsResponse' in namespace 'http://gls-group.eu/Tracking/' has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'History' in namespace 'http://gls-group.eu/Tracking/'.*

But you realy should be using some for of soap wraper, this should validate the response against the schema in the WSDL, and also sort out all the failure messages correctly. There are tools to generate SOAP wrappers for most platforms and langauges.

Note: Validation in this example was done using .Net classes.

Answer (score 0):

Add your all mandatory entities with its namespace in Hashmap/Map , while parsing response read entity one by one and check that entity is present in Map or not.

Comment: I'm using external tooling to validate the soap response with a xsd. So I just need to have an xsd which I can import in my tooling. So there is no way I can solve this programmatically.